# Менеджер пакетов pip и установленные python-пакеты

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Возникла следующая проблема. Для подтверждения специально поставил чистую в виртуалку - на ней тоже самое. Система - Debian Testing. Pip изначально ставил через apt-get. Но в нем выше 9 версии нету.

```
kraamis@debian:~$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

При попытке сранить версии пакетов на выходе следующее

```
kraamis@debian:~$ pip3 list -o
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 157, in run
    packages = self.get_outdated(packages, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 168, in get_outdated
    dist for dist in self.iter_packages_latest_infos(packages, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 169, in <listcomp>
    if dist.latest_version > dist.parsed_version
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'Version'
```

После обновления pip

```
kraamis@debian:~$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% || 1.3MB 343kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1

kraamis@debian:~$ pip3 list -o
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

kraamis@debian:~$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Куда тыкать?

Comment: Не нужно было обновлять pip в обход системного менеджера пакетов

Comment: Я его изначально ставил через apt-get. Но в нем выше 9 версии нету. добавил в текст.

Comment: И даже если остаться на 9.0.1 - он тоже не работает.

Comment: Версии каких пакетов вы хотите сравнить? Установленных с помощью `pip`? Попробуйте `pip freeze`

Comment: Мне нужна табличка, какие установленные и какие есть в репозиториях. за это отвечает команда `pip3 list -o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С новым pip 18 такой проблемы нет.